# gridArea React inline style with a variable

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, inline-styles

I'm trying to return a number of divs and dynamically place them in a grid. I've never tried this before, and I think my syntax may be off. None of the divs are appearing. The template is working, and the divs should currently fill grid container and turn it black with a button.

```
export const DayColumn = ({ day }) => {
  const { timeColumn } = useTableContext();

  return (
    <Wrapper gridInterval={timeColumn.length}>
      <h2>{day}</h2>
      {timeColumn.forEach((_, index) => {
        index++;
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            className='task-slot'
            style={{ gridArea: `${index + 1} / 1 / ${index + 2} / 2;` }}
          >
            <h1>text</h1>
            <BsPlusSquareFill />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

The styled component

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: ${(props) => `100px repeat(${props.gridInterval}, 1fr);`};
  grid-gap: 3px;
  background-color: var(--clr-background-dark3);
  border-radius: 7px;
  h2 {
    justify-self: center;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: var(--clr-text-light);
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  .task-slot {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Needed to use `map` instead of `forEach`